# FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (junos_logging) module: port Supported parameters include: active, aggregate, dest,}

Tags: logging, ansible, juniper

I'm getting the error in the title when trying to configure syslog on Juniper devices using Ansible.

This is my config:

- name: Update juniper logging configuration
  hosts: all
  collections:

  - junipernetworks.junos
    roles:
  - juniper.junos
    connection: local
    gather_facts: yes
- name: configure test syslog
  junos_logging:
  dest: host
  name: test.syslog.com
  facility: any
  level: info
  port: 1500

I tried to change the connection from local to ansible.netcommon.netconf and that returned more errors. also tried to configure host_port 1500 instead of port, I am seeing the same error message.
i didn't have the collection explicitly mentioned in the script, so i added that in. it works without mentioning the port but i do have to add that in.
Can someone help please?